# using extern with same parameter name inside function

Tags: c, extern

I have this c code that have a global variable

main_prog.c

```
PLD po;
int main(){}
```

i have this function in the definition

functiondef.c

```
void function(PLD po)
{
  extern po;
}
```

what my problem is that how do the compiler know that it is using the extern po or the parameter po??

Comment: @self. duplicate symbol?

Comment: @Till is there a way to use the global variable in the other files? not just extern.

Comment: @Till My bad, I didn't see the PLD po argument in the function.

Comment: @kwatford just askin if there is a way

Comment: @user3444777 That does not compile. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Interesting; it does compile, not even a warning (clang). The result is; the parameter is ignored and the global is used.

Comment: @self. another way of accessing the po global variable inside a function on different file with same parameter name

Comment: @Till but how do you access the parameter? if it is already ignored?

Comment: @Till I don't think it should compile. What value do you get?

Comment: @self. Just tried to setup this on ideone but their compiler does not allow this. My testcase: http://ideone.com/TsrFIR - as said before, it builds on clang (Xcode 5.1) and outputs 17.

Comment: @self. Hah, when building in C++ mode, this compiles fine on gcc4.8.1: http://ideone.com/chGyDy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely access the extern variable if you declare it in a different scope.

```
void function(PLD po)
{

    {
        extern PLD po;    //this is the po declared in main
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer.  -100000 for enabling him to write absolutely, unbelievable horrible code :)

Comment: Note that `extern po;` declares `po` to be of type `int`, and is not allowed in either C99 or C11.  It was allowed in C89 as a concession to existing code that used the technique.  Unless `PLD` is a synonym for `int`, the behaviour when access a variable of type `PLD` as if it is an `int` is undefined.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Fixed. This was my original intent.

Comment: It actually wasn't so much a comment directed at you and your answer as aimed at the code in the question.